# How to solve 2 classes in dependency with exact same path&name?

Tags: sbt, dependency-management

I'm using SBT to manage dependencies. I added 2 jars AAA and BBB into my project. However, both AAA and BBB have a class with exact same name and path like com.ccc.ddd.eee.fff.foo.java.

Now, the compiler does NOT complain. However, when I import foo.java, it always comes from jar AAA although, unfortunately, I want it to come from jar BBB.

Any suggestions about how to solve this puzzle? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I was using libraryDependencies +=, managed dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say how the 2 jars were added; it would be helpful to see your `build.sbt`.

That said, the classpath is affected by the order in which you list the dependencies. If you are using unmanaged dependencies, and you want a specific version of a class to be found, list that library dependency first.

If they were specified as managed dependencies, it is more common to try something like:

```
libraryDependencies += "foo" % "bar" % "x.y.z" exclude("org.domain", "AAA")
```

or:

```
ivyXML :=
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.domain" name="AAA" rev="x.y.z">
      <exclude module="activation"/>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

There is more information here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html